# Independent Contractor to an US law firm

Tags: taxes, income

please advise me on the concerns of income tax i have. I'm an Indian citizen residing in India. I'm working for an Law frim in US as an independent contractor. i'm not sure if i'm liable for paying US IT, Since my income generated in US. Should i pay my IT returns in India as i'm residing in India. Or is the case worse, should i pay in both the countries. I've never been to USA. I'll probably be going to USA on June 2015. Please advise explicitly. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you work *while in the US* then you're most definitely liable for income tax in the US (in addition to your income tax liability in India).

If you're working in India - then, unless you are otherwise a US tax resident (i.e.: US citizen, green card holder, spent enough time in the US to qualify under substantial presence test, or married to such a person and made an election to file jointly), you have no US tax liability. You obviously have Indian tax liability.

Of course, I'm just a random person on the Internet. For a qualified tax advice talk to a US-licensed tax adviser (EA/CPA licensed in a US State).